# Why I can not use 'foreach' with Dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have the following class definition :

```
  [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    public class Models
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Dictionary<string, string> models { get; set; }
        public Models()
        {
            models = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }
    }
```

Then I have a method to get the dictionary to write to a ini file.

```
public bool write_all_model_names(Models models)
{
    bool write_status = false;
    try
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> model in models)
        {
            Write(model.Key, model.Value);
        }
        write_status = true;
    }
    catch
    {

    }
    return write_status;
}
```

I get the following error when I try to compile.

```
**Error**   CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Models' because 'Models' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'  CPTD_SJQ_UI
```

'models' is a dictionary list so why not loop through ?

Comment: Because it's not a dictionary list, it is a class with a dictionary as a property. `foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> model in models.models)` would work though, albeit you should consider renaming

Comment: You've confused yourself because you've named both the parameter and the property it contains `models`. If you follow .NET naming conventions, you wouldn't have this confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a direct consequence of the terrible naming scheme you use: in the `foreach` line you refer to the `Models` class by the `models` name, whereas what you want to iterate over is the `models` property in your `Models` class.

So, in short:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> model in models.models)
```

Again, note how bad your naming is.

Answer (score 1):

in that function `models` is an object of type `Models`.  So you would have to use

`foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> model in models.models)`